# how to parse xml into hash map when few attributes are missing for different enteries

Tags: java, xml

Below is the xml I am converting into hash map:

```
<dsml>
    <entries>
        <entry dn="uid=7686,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
            <att name="uid">
                <value>7568766</value>
            </att>
            <att name="email">
                <value>new@gmail.com</value>
            </att>
            <att name="callname">
                <value>John</value>
            </att>
        </entry>
        <entry dn="uid=7689,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
            <att name="uid">
                <value>7678766</value>
            </att>
            <att name="callname">
                <value>Mike</value>
            </att>
        </entry>
        <entry dn="uid=7690,c=in,ou=pages,o=example.com">
            <att name="uid">
                <value>75858766</value>
            </att>
            <att name="email">
                <value>old@gmail.com</value>
            </att>
            <att name="callname">
                <value>rahul</value>
            </att>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</dsml>
```

As you can see that one of the entry does not contain email attribute and that is what which is creating the issue. Below is the code I am using to convert it into hashmap:

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expr = "//dsml/entries/entry/att[@name = 'callname']/value";
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expr, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

String expr1 = "/dsml/directory-entries/entry/attr[@name = 'email']/value";
NodeList n2 = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expr1, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);


Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0; i<=2;i++){
    map.put(nl.item(i).getTextContent(), n2.item(i).getTextContent());

    System.out.println(nl.item(i).getTextContent());
    System.out.println(n2.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

The output of this code is:
John
new@gmail.com
Mike
old@gmail.com
rahul
exceptionnull

Is there any way that if some attribute is not present then it should be skipped rather than fetching the value from next entry attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not correct as it cannot detect cases where you have an entry with only the `email` followed by an entry with only `callname`, it will be seen as it is the same entry and then mixed two information that are not even related. What I propose is to modify your `XPath` in order to keep only the entries that have both the `email` and the `callname`.

Here is how I would do it:

```
// Keep only entries that have both email and callname
String expr = "/dsml/entries/entry[att[@name = 'email'] and att[@name = 'callname']]/att[@name = 'email' or @name = 'callname']/value";
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expr, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i< nl.getLength(); i++){
    Node node = nl.item(i);
    String name, email;
    // Check whether the current value is the value of the email or callname
    if ("callnamen".equals(node.getParentNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent())) {
        name = node.getTextContent();
        email = nl.item(++i).getTextContent();
    } else {
        name = nl.item(++i).getTextContent();
        email = node.getTextContent();
    }
    map.put(name, email);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

**Output:**

```
{rahul=old@gmail.com, John=new@gmail.com}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi nicholas, it would be great help if you could explain that how you created xpath and how the heirarchy is working for this command:

**("callnamen".equals(node.getParentNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent())**

Comment: /dsml/entries/entry[att[@name = 'email'] and att[@name = 'callname']] will select all the entries that have a child element `attr` with the attribute name = "email" and another one with the attribute name = "callname". Then  /att[@name = 'email' or @name = 'callname']/value will select all the element `value` whose parent node `att` has an attribute name whose value is email or callname

Comment: This (node.getParentNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").g‌​etTextContent()) simply returns the value of the attribute name of the parent of the current node which is a node value in this case so it will get the value of the attribute name of the node attr

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the content of any element is null and accordingly update your hash map. For instance :

```
 map.put(nl.item(i).getTextContent(), n2.item(i).getTextContent()==null?"":n2.item(i).getTextContent());
```

Or just put a check beforehand to check for nulls :

```
if(nl.item(i).getTextContent()!=null && n2.item(i).getTextContent()!=null){
//Put into map
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried this approach but as you can see that in second entry there is no attribute of Email address as such, so there will be no null value for it as such attribute doesn't exist for second entry. The hash map will still assign Mike (Key) the Value "old@gmail.com" which is actually should be value of "rahul".